# Applying Bokeh Formatter Manually

Tags: bokeh

How do I apply a Bokeh formatter manually, from Python? Not just setting up a formatter or a callback, but doing it explicitly. Ideally it would be something like this:

```
formatter = bokeh.models.NumeralTickFormatter(format='0.00')
formatter.apply(-123.123) # => -123.12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Amost all of the actual work of Bokeh is actually done by the runtime JavaScript library BokehJS, in a browser. There is no Python implementation of `NumeralTickFormatter` or any other Bokeh model. All of the models in `bokeh.models` on the "Python side" are just thin declarative structs that only exist for the purpose of  mirroring the object graph into JavaScript.